# Subdomain with SSL on wildcard ssl cert

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, debian-wheezy

I setup a subdomain in my sites-available folder, enabled it and done everything needed so that it restarts apache2 with no errors (changing *default*:443 to *:443, adding NameVirtualHost *:443 to ports.conf, etc).

The subdomain now works perfectly but when I try to access any page using SSL on the main domain it jumps to my error page. It seems to have taken over all SSL.

Ex: subdomain.domain.com

Apache2 error: File does not exist: /var/www/subdomain/foldername

It should not be reading from the subdomain folder for this. My guess is it is a problem in my  virtual host setup below:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain/
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bundle.crt
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
    </VirtualHost>
```

Results of apachectl -S:

```
    VirtualHost configuration:
    wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
    *:443    is a NameVirtualHost
             default server subdomain.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subdomain.domain.com:1)
             port 443 namevhost subdomain.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subdomain.domain.com:1)
             port 443 namevhost *.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
    *:80     is a NameVirtualHost
             default server production1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
             port 80 namevhost production1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
    Syntax OK
```

Comment: Can you provide the output from `apachectl -S`?

Comment: Added to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL virtual host configurations are just like normal ones; they don't inherit directives from the corresponding non-SSL vhost configurations or anything.

Since you have specified the directive `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain/`, apache will use this folder for all the requests which match this vhost (eg. for `subdomain.domain.com`).  You should change this to the actual location you'd like it to use for the webroot.

Also, one point: you don't need to specify a name in `ServerAlias` if it's the `ServerName`.

That you are using wildcard SSL isn't particularly relevant to this problem.

Also, ensure that each site you have has its own SSL virtualhost configuration parallel with the cleartext one.  Be aware that the default vhost for port 443 (the first one on the search path in alphabetical order) will be used if the client doesn't support SNI but is using SSL.

Looking at your `apachectl -S` output, you will need to do a few things:

- Rename your default SSL vhost config file so that it is alphabetically before all others
- Remove the wildcard `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` from the default SSL vhost and replace it with `domain.com` (and `www.domain.com` if you like).  It will match all unmatched subdomains by virtue of being the default; the wildcard will make it match everything so that `subdomain.domain.com` matches the default vhost too.

Comment: Yes but it is also using it for a URL like https://www.domain.com/login as per my confusion and the error log.

Comment: Yes, I was in the middle of typing that last bit out.